# how to use lxml to get the url

Tags: python, html, lxml

I want to know how to use lxml to get a url,and then I can use xpath to parse the data I want .
Please guide me,thank you very much.

```
res = requests.get('http://www.ipeen.com.tw/comment/778246')
doc = parse(res.content)
name = doc.xpath("//meta[@itemprop='name']/@content")               
print name
```

There are errors in my code:

```
   doc = parse(res.content)
  File "/Users/ome/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 786, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3299, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72655)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106263)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1817, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106564)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1721, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105561)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1122, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:100456)
  File "parser.pxi", line 580, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:94543)
  File "parser.pxi", line 690, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96003)
  File "parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:95015)
IOError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.content` is a string, an HTML string.

You need to use [`lxml.html.fromstring()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html):

```
import lxml.html
import requests

res = requests.get('http://www.ipeen.com.tw/comment/778246')

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)
name = doc.xpath(".//meta[@itemprop='name']/@content")   
print name
```

Comment: Thanks,is this a normal way to parse a url with html format ?  I was used to use scrapy,I just gave spider the link and then I can use xpath.

Comment: @user2492364 yup, in case of `requests` it is a normal way. If you would use `urllib2`, then you could use `lxml.html.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))` since `urlopen()` returns a file-like object.

Comment: @user2492364 just FYI, your xpath returns an empty list since there is no really `meta` tag with attribute `itemprop="name"` on the page.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can move on now

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `res.content` is a string containing the contents of the page. `parse` takes a filename or file-like object. Thus, you are using the page content as the name of a file. This is probably not what you want. To construct a tree from a string, use `fromstring` rather than `parse`.

Comment: As in lxml there are two major libs etree and html for xml processing. @alecxe showed html and you are telling about etree i.e. etree.parse----is it?

Comment: @SIslam: I suppose you’d be using `lxml.html` if you’re dealing with HTML and `lxml.etree` if you’re dealing with XML. I’m guessing I meant `lxml.etree` since that’s what was in the question but it’s kind of a moot point since you’re only changing 5 letters one way or the other.

Comment: ,what about lxml.html.parse though it does not proceed with fragmented document.

Comment: I think if xml is not fragmented only then lxml.html.parse may be used.However it is an another option?

Comment: @fragment is broken page i think.document is full page in case of html- i think.

Comment: @SIslam: Then yes, `lxml.html` handles broken documents better.